# Python 3.6.2/Selenium 2.0/AJAX - How to wait for script to conclude server request

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

So, I have a Web application at work that need to gather information and build some reports and run some basic data analysis.

The thing is that I'm a complete newbie to HTML, Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML), Python and Selenium.

What I gather so far is this:

1. Ajax nature is to perform asynchronous Web Browser activities and in my case, sending server requests to push/pull some data
2. Selenium handles the asynchronous events performing `Wait` actions like:

   - time.sleep('time in ms') # using the time library. So not REALLY Selenium;
   - Explicit Waits: you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code;

---

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    delay_time = 10 # how much time until raises NoExeption in Selenium    

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")

    webDriverWait(driver,delay_time)\
    .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'IdOfMyElement')))`
```

> EC stands for expected conditions represented by:
>
> > title_is;
> >
> > title_contains;
> >
> > presence_of_element_located
> >
> > visibility_of_element_located
> >
> > visibility_of
> >
> > presence_of_all_elements_located
> >
> > text_to_be_present_in_element
> >
> > text_to_be_present_in_element_value
> >
> > frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it
> >
> > invisibility_of_element_located
> >
> > element_to_be_clickable
> >
> > staleness_of
> >
> > element_to_be_selected
> >
> > element_located_to_be_selected
> >
> > element_selection_state_to_be
> >
> > element_located_selection_state_to_be
> >
> > alert_is_present

---

- Implicit Waits: tell WebDriver to poll the DOM (Document Object Model) for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available;
  `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`-
- Executing JavaScript using Java and applies wait: j Query keeps a count of how many Ajax calls are active in its query.active variable;
- FluentWait:  FluentWait option to handle uncertain waits;
- WebdriverWait: use ExpectedCondition and WebDriverWait strategy.

What to use since I have the following situation:

Button to send a clear request via Ajax.

```
<div id="div_39_1_3" class="Button  CoachView CPP BPMHSectionChild CoachView_show" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_b24acf10_7ca3_40fa_b73f_782cddfd48e6.Button" data-binding="local.clearButton" data-bindingtype="boolean" data-config="config175" data-viewid="GhostClear" data-eventid="boundaryEvent_42" data-ibmbpm-layoutpreview="horizontal" control-name="/GhostClear"> 
    <button class="btn btn-labeled"><span class="btn-label icon fa fa-times"></span>Clear</button></div>
```

This is the event of the button:
    `function(a) {!e._instance.btn.disabled && 
    c.ui.executeEventHandlingFunction(e, e._proto.EVT_ONCLICK) && 
    (e._instance.multiClicks || (e._instance.btn.disabled = !0, 
    f.add(e._instance.btn, "disabled")), e.context.binding && 
    e.context.binding.set("value", !0), e.context.trigger(function(a) {
    e._instance.btn.disabled = !1;
    f.remove(e._instance.btn, "disabled");
    setTimeout(function() {
      c.ui.executeEventHandlingFunction(e, e._proto.EVT_ONBOUNDARYEVT, 
    a.status)
    })
  }, {
    callBackForAll: !0
  }))
}`

Then, my network informs that the ajaxCoach proceeds to the following requests

[image: Networkflow for the clear button]

Is it possible to selenium to see/find if an AJAX action 
concluded the page actualization action in Python?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it depends on the library used by the page to perform the ajax requests. The idea is to wait for a status or for the count of pending requests to be 0.

Comment: @FlorentB., thank you for your reply. I tried to find something about counting the pending requests but found nothing either in Selenium or Ajax Js Scripting with it. Do you have an example on how to proceed with that?

Comment: an example is useless without knowing exactly how the page handles the requests. Add a break-point for the click and run the code step by step to find out which library is used.

Comment: @FlorentB.For more that I could gather (since I had to learn the main concepts of JS and it's library's, after some blackboxing and debugging, dojo.js (hope that some valid answer) is called in the stack and some interaction with some functions inside happen. Just could not find status or requests in the process.

Comment: You can check for an `onloadend` event in js. And execute a script to return that value into python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have jquery on the page, you can define the button with jquery
and wait until the event function is ready.
for your question:

```
    driver.execute_script('button = $("#div_39_1_3");')
    events = driver.execute_script('return $._data(button[0], 
    "events");')
```

now you need to wait until events variable is not none.